# How to use information from a document to calculate total pay with java program

Tags: java, java-io

I made a program that reads text files and a program that calculates total pay including overtime. How can the two be combined to make a program that takes the employee's info from a text file to calculate the total pay rather than taking the info from user input???

Here is my code for reading a text file:

```
System.out.println("Reading File ......");

   String fileName="random.txt";
   try{

      FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

      BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

      String line;

      while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
        System.out.println(line);
      }

      bufferReader.close();

   }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());                      
   }
```

and here is my code for calculating total pay:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 double rate;
 double hoursWorked;
 double regularPay;
 double overtimePay;
 final int FULL_WEEK = 40;
 final double OT_RATE = 1.5;


  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("What is your first name? ");
  String firstname = keyboard.nextLine();
  System.out.print("What is your last name? ");
  String lastname = keyboard.nextLine ();
  System.out.print ("What is your social security #? ");
  String ss = keyboard.nextLine();
  System.out.print("How many hours did you work this week? ");
  hoursWorked = keyboard.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("How much are you paid an hour? ");
  rate = keyboard.nextDouble();

  if(hoursWorked > FULL_WEEK)
  {
     regularPay = FULL_WEEK * rate;
     overtimePay = (hoursWorked - FULL_WEEK) * OT_RATE * rate;
  }
  else
  {
     regularPay = hoursWorked * rate;
     overtimePay = 0.0;
  }
  System.out.println("----------------------------");
  System.out.println("Frist name: " + firstname);
  System.out.println("Last name: " + lastname);
  System.out.println("SS#: " + ss);
  System.out.println("Regular pay is " + regularPay + "\nOvertime pay is " + overtimePay);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on how your data is structured, for instance, employees record in `random.file` are listed as follows:

> Harry Poter 100001 40  100
>
> Anakin Skywalker 100002 50 100
>
> ...

Each of the records is separated by whitespace, now, our data is ready, let's create a POJO(in a sperate file) for employee:

```
public class Employee {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String securityNum;
    float workingHoursPerWeek;
    float salariesPerHour;
    float regularPay;
    float overtimePay;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSecurityNum() {
        return securityNum;
    }

    public void setSecurityNum(String securityNum) {
        this.securityNum = securityNum;
    }

    public float getWorkingHoursPerWeek() {
        return workingHoursPerWeek;
    }

    public void setWorkingHoursPerWeek(float workingHoursPerWeek) {
        this.workingHoursPerWeek = workingHoursPerWeek;
    }

    public float getSalariesPerHour() {
        return salariesPerHour;
    }

    public void setSalariesPerHour(float salariesPerHour) {
        this.salariesPerHour = salariesPerHour;
    }

    public float getRegularPay() {
        return regularPay;
    }

    public void setRegularPay(float regularPay) {
        this.regularPay = regularPay;
    }

    public float getOvertimePay() {
        return overtimePay;
    }

    public void setOvertimePay(float overtimePay) {
        this.overtimePay = overtimePay;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", securityNum='" + securityNum + '\'' +
                ", workingHoursPerWeek=" + workingHoursPerWeek +
                ", salariesPerHour=" + salariesPerHour +
                ", regularPay=" + regularPay +
                ", overtimePay=" + overtimePay +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and a new static function `open` alongside `main()` to convert the records into a `List`:

```
public static List<Employee> open(String fileName) {
    List<Employee> employees;
    BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
    try{

        bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        String line;
        employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setFirstName(tokens[0]);
            employee.setLastName(tokens[1]);
            employee.setSecurityNum(tokens[2]);
            employee.setWorkingHoursPerWeek(Float.valueOf(tokens[3]));
            employee.setSalariesPerHour(Float.valueOf(tokens[4]));
            employees.add(employee);
        }

        return employees;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return new ArrayList<Employee>();
}
```

in main, we calculate salaries for every employee and print them out finally:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double rate;
    double hoursWorked;
    double regularPay;
    double overtimePay;
    final int FULL_WEEK = 40;
    final double OT_RATE = 1.5;
    List<Employee> employees = open("Your random file path goes here.");
    for(Employee employee : employees) {
        hoursWorked = employee.getWorkingHoursPerWeek();
        rate = employee.getSalariesPerHour();

        if(hoursWorked > FULL_WEEK)
        {
            employee.setRegularPay(FULL_WEEK * rate);
            employee.setOvertimePay((hoursWorked - FULL_WEEK) * OT_RATE * rate);
        }
        else
        {
            employee.setRegularPay(hoursWorked * rate);
            employee.setOvertimePay(0.0);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(employees);

}
```